# Make Part of table cell text bold C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, styling

I have a following code:

```
DataSourceSelectArguments sr = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
DataView dv = DurationSQL.Select(sr) as DataView;

if (dv.Count != 0)
{
    GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "Duration: \r" + dv[0][0].ToString() + "\r|";
}
```

I would like to make the static text:

> Duration:

Displayed in bold while the rest of the text has no styling applied any way to achieve this?

Comment: you need to create a label or span and set the style to that. Then add that label or span to the Table cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can put HTML into the cell text to achieve this, while at the same time preventing that HTML from being HtmlEncoded, like this:

**Put HTML into the cell:**

```
GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "<b>Duration:</b><br />"
                                + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dv[0][0].ToString()) + "<br />|";
```

I included a call to `.HtmlEncode()`, but if the value is e.g. a number you may even skip that.

**Prevent HTML from being encoded** (use it for your first column, based on the fact that you use Cells[0]):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourColumn" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string text = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
            var span1 = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
            span1.InnerHtml = "<strong>Duration:</strong> \r" + text;
            GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = span1.InnerHtml;
```

Seemed to work thanks for the comment